# How do I create a Java SOAP web service from a .WSDL file that includes methods with duplicate parameter names?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I've generated the Java classes from the .WSDL file, but am seeing errors:

`Parameter names must be unique: 'myParam'`

myParam is the name of a field in the request object and the response object, so it appears as both an IN and an OUT @WebParam in the @WebMethod declaration (with the OUT parameters contained in Holders). The two parameters have different types, so I can't combine them into an INOUT parameter.

How do I fix this issue while maintaining compliance with the .WSDL spec?

**Edit for clarity:**

Request Type:

```
<xs:complexType name="myRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="myParam" type="he:myParamType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Response Type:

```
<xs:complexType name="myResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="myParam" type="he:someOtherType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Because of this, the same operation will have two parameters with the `name` attribute set to "myParam", which is invalid.

Comment: How did you do the failing conversion and with what software?

Comment: I used the jaxws-maven-plugin. The conversion runs when Maven refreshes the Eclipse project. I'm not sure the conversion "failed," as the Java code does match the .WSDL, but Eclipse is telling me it's invalid.

Comment: You should show some relevant code or sections from the WSDL that cause the issue you are describing.

Comment: See my edit above.